# svg dropshadow problem in Chrome: instead of adding the shadow to only the graphic the shadow is being added to the actual container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am trying to add a Gaussian drop shadow to a SVG `path` but for some reason this doesn't seem to work that great in Chrome, instead of adding the shadow to only the graphic the shadow is being added to the actual container? This views perfectly in ff?

How to make this work correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/NAM8d/2/

Comment: It looks rather nice to me in Chrome 14.0.835.29 dev on Mac OS X 10.7. [Screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/3c465y10/)

Comment: how weird, im using chrome on windows and getting a totally different result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox renders the shadow but truncates the image (on your example)
Chrome, Safari, Opera - no shadow 
been wondering why all the differences myself...

BUT I've found Opera renders shadows fine - for SVGs exported from Illustrator CS5 - although Safari, Chrome and Firefox won't...
Guess it's early days for SVGs to become the staple web graphic file type (much anticipated)
Sad about all the differences though ... Chrome is the smoothest for SVG animation I've found

Comment: Firefox's rendering is correct. If you don't supply a width or height for the svg element it should be sized at the default replaced element size of 300 x 150 according to the CSS specification.